# Any jQuery plugins for tables fixed header and sorting together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I've been looking at ways to make a table have a fixed header especially in IE8. I noticed that most jquery plugins can achieve this but in doing so they split the table into two sections usually 2 separate divs one containing the thead stuff and the other tbody

This works fantastic but how would I go about adding sorting to the table. Most jquery plugins I found only work when the table contains a thead and tbody in one.

Are there any jquery plugins that can do this? Ideally it would be great if the jQuery plugin like tablesorter can be given an id for thead an one for tbody

I did come across this demo which is exactly what I need but it's using Prototype instead of jquery

[Demo scroll to the bottom to Table 6 (it has scrolling and sorting)](http://tetlaw.id.au/upload/pages/table-sorting-with-prototype/)

Cheers

Rob

Comment: Nothing wrong with prototype but my website is currently using jquery and would prefer not having to load up another script just for this task if worse comes to worse I'll have to include it, but if there was some other way that would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A section of this blog combines jquery scrollablefixedheadertable and jquery tablesorter

Here's the link.
http://jeromebulanadi.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/scrollable-fixed-header-table-a-jquery-plugin/#integration

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/

Tablefixedheader may not clearly state this, but as seen in example #5, it can quite simply be modified to be sortable.

Comment: I prefer this solution